# Create per-instance property descriptor?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, propertydescriptor

Usually Python descriptor are defined as class attributes. But in my case, I want every object instance to have different set descriptors that depends on the input. For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for attr, val in kwargs.items():
      self.__dict__[attr] = MyDescriptor(val)
```

Each object are have different set of attributes that are decided at instantiation time. Since these are one-off objects, it is not convenient to first subclass them.

```
tv = MyClass(type="tv", size="30")
smartphone = MyClass(type="phone", os="android")

tv.size   # do something smart with the descriptor
```

Assign Descriptor to the object does not seem to work. If I try to access the attribute, I got something like

```
<property at 0x4067cf0>
```

Do you know why is this not working? Is there any work around?

Comment: Why not using different subclasses of MyClass with overriden descriptors?

Comment: Edited to add more example. I guess per-instance descriptor just cannot be done. I have worked around it using __getattr__. Still don't understand the underlying language constraint though.

Comment: Descriptors only work at the class level, sorry.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this? It seems like a `NamedTuple` or a `dict` would be sufficient as a data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not working because you have to assign the descriptor to the class of the object.

```
class Descriptor:

    def __get__(...):
        # this is called when the value is got

    def __set__(...
    def __del__(...
```

if you write

```
obj.attr
=> type(obj).__getattribute__(obj, 'attr') is called
=> obj.__dict__['attr'] is returned if there else:
=> type(obj).__dict__['attr'] is looked up
if this contains a descriptor object then this is used.
```

so it does not work because the type dictionairy is looked up for descriptors and not the object dictionairy.

there are possible work arounds:

1. put the descriptor into the class and make it use e.g. obj.xxxattr to store the value. 
   If there is only one descriptor behaviour this works.
2. overwrite **setattr** and **getattr** and **delattr** to respond to discriptors.
3. put a discriptor into the class that responds to descriptors stored in the object dictionairy.

Answer (score 2):

You are using descriptors in the wrong way.

Descriptors don't make sense on an instance level. After all the `__get__`/`__set__`
methods give you access to the `instance` of the class.

Without knowing what exactly you want to do, I'd suggest you put the per-instance
logic inside the `__set__` method, by checking who is the "caller/instance" and act accordingly.

Otherwise tell us what you are trying to achieve, so that we can propose alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I dynamically create instances by `exec`ing a made-up class. This may suit your use case.

```
def make_myclass(**kwargs):

    class MyDescriptor(object):
        def __init__(self, val):
            self.val = val

        def __get__(self, obj, cls):
            return self.val

        def __set__(self, obj, val):
            self.val = val

    cls = 'class MyClass(object):\n{}'.format('\n'.join('    {0} = MyDescriptor({0})'.format(k) for k in kwargs))

    #check if names in kwargs collide with local names
    for key in kwargs:
        if key in locals():
            raise Exception('name "{}" collides with local name'.format(key))

    kwargs.update(locals())
    exec(cls, kwargs, locals())
    return MyClass()
```

Test;

```
In [577]: tv = make_myclass(type="tv", size="30")

In [578]: tv.type
Out[578]: 'tv'

In [579]: tv.size
Out[579]: '30'

In [580]: tv.__dict__
Out[580]: {}
```

But the instances are of different class.

```
In [581]: phone = make_myclass(type='phone')

In [582]: phone.type
Out[582]: 'phone'

In [583]: tv.type
Out[583]: 'tv'

In [584]: isinstance(tv,type(phone))
Out[584]: False

In [585]: isinstance(phone,type(tv))
Out[585]: False

In [586]: type(tv)
Out[586]: MyClass

In [587]: type(phone)
Out[587]: MyClass

In [588]: type(phone) is type(tv)
Out[588]: False
```

Comment: On the good side, performance will be better than with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35657853/208880); on the down side, instances are not the same class, and there could be confusion because they all have the same class name.  Still, a good solution in the appropriate circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a use-case for [named tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working is because Python only checks for descriptors when looking up attributes on the class, not on the instance; the methods in question are:

- [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)
- [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)
- [`__delattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delattr__)

It is possible to override those methods on your class in order to implement the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol) on instances as well as classes:

```
# do not use in production, example code only, needs more checks
class ClassAllowingInstanceDescriptors(object):
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        res = self.__dict__.get(name)
        for method in ('__get__', '__set__', '__delete__'):
            if hasattr(res, method):
                # we have a descriptor, use it
                res = res.__delete__(name)
                break
        else:
            res = object.__delattr__(self, name)
        return res
    def __getattribute__(self, *args):
        res = object.__getattribute__(self, *args)
        for method in ('__get__', '__set__', '__delete__'):
            if hasattr(res, method):
                # we have a descriptor, call it
                res = res.__get__(self, self.__class__)
        return res
    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        # check if object already exists
        res = self.__dict__.get(name)
        for method in ('__get__', '__set__', '__delete__'):
            if hasattr(res, method):
                # we have a descriptor, use it
                res = res.__set__(self, val)
                break
        else:
            res = object.__setattr__(self, name, val)
        return res
    @property
    def world(self):
        return 'hello!'
```

When the above class is used as below:

```
huh = ClassAllowingInstanceDescriptors()
print(huh.world)
huh.uni = 'BIG'
print(huh.uni)
huh.huh = property(lambda *a: 'really?')
print(huh.huh)
print('*' * 50)
try:
    del huh.world
except Exception, e:
    print(e)
print(huh.world)
print('*' * 50)
try:
    del huh.huh
except Exception, e:
    print(e)
print(huh.huh)
```

The results are:

> hello!
>
> BIG
>
> really?
>
> ---
>
> can't delete attribute
>
> hello!
>
> ---
>
> can't delete attribute
>
> really?